# как сделать UPDATE одного поля по разным условиям

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Как эти два UPDATE сделать одним запросом:

```
UPDATE employees  
SET
salary = salary * 2 
WHERE EXISTS  (
            SELECT 1
            FROM sales s
            WHERE s.employee_id = employees.id 
            AND
            YEAR(CAST(sales_time AS DATE)) = 2017
            HAVING SUM(s.amount) >= 10000
            )

UPDATE employees
SET
salary = salary *1.5 
WHERE EXISTS  (
            SELECT e.first_name, SUM(s.amount) as sum_amount, e.salary *20 as salary
            FROM sales s join employees e on s.employee_id = e.id
            GROUP BY e.salary, e.first_name, sales_time
            HAVING (SUM (amount) < 10000 
            AND SUM (amount) > salary *20) 
            AND YEAR(CAST(sales_time AS DATE)) = 2017
            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал условие, по которому срабатывают сразу 2 этих апдейта.
Например так:

```
if (нажата какая то кнопка) {


UPDATE employees  
SET
salary = salary * 2 
WHERE EXISTS  (
        SELECT 1
        FROM sales s
        WHERE s.employee_id = employees.id 
        AND
        YEAR(CAST(sales_time AS DATE)) = 2017
        HAVING SUM(s.amount) >= 10000
        )

UPDATE employees
SET
salary = salary *1.5 
WHERE EXISTS  (
        SELECT e.first_name, SUM(s.amount) as sum_amount, e.salary *20 
as  salary
        FROM sales s join employees e on s.employee_id = e.id
        GROUP BY e.salary, e.first_name, sales_time
        HAVING (SUM (amount) < 10000 
        AND SUM (amount) > salary *20) 
        AND YEAR(CAST(sales_time AS DATE)) = 2017
        )

}
```

Comment: у меня без привязки к нопке

Comment: ну к чему то есть привязка? Через условный оператор можно что угодно привязать. При каком действии происходит UPDATE таблиц?

Comment: Обновить значение salary в таблице employees установив заработные платы для
сотрудников по следующим правилам:
Если итоговая выручка за последний год составляет от 10000 и более - удвоить текущее
значение.
Если выручка меньше 10000 но больше чем 20 * salary сотрудника - умножить значение
salary на 1.5

Comment: Так и пишите в коде:       if (значение итоговой выручки >= 10000){UPDATE employees
SET salary = salary * 2 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM sales s WHERE s.employee_id = employees.id AND YEAR(CAST(sales_time AS DATE)) = 2017 HAVING SUM(s.amount) >= 10000 )}      и по этому же принципу второй update

Comment: спасибо, понятно

Comment: если помог, жмякни, что я дал ответ, а то я без 50 баллов тут даже коментить не могу)

Answer (score 0):

Можно одним запросом:

```
UPDATE e
    SET salary = CASE
        WHEN y.year_amount >= 10000 THEN e.salary*2
        WHEN y.year_amount < 10000 AND m.sum_amount > e.salary*20 THEN e.salary*1.5
        ELSE e.salary
        END
--  SELECT m.sum_amount, e.salary, e.*
FROM employees e
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT SUM(s.amount) year_amount
        FROM sales s
        WHERE YEAR(CAST(sales_time AS DATE)) = 2017
    ) y
    JOIN (
        SELECT s.employee_id, 
            SUM(s.amount) as sum_amount
        FROM sales s 
        WHERE YEAR(CAST(sales_time AS DATE)) = 2017
        GROUP BY s.employee_id
    ) m ON m.employee_id = e.id
```